# How to use square brackets for a string evaluation in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, eval

Using square brackets for string evaluation, I am trying to make `[inputString]` return `320`. 
Any ideas how to do it?

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim inputString As String
    inputString = "20+300"
    Debug.Print Application.Evaluate(inputString)   'ok
    Debug.Print Evaluate([inputString])             'ok
    Debug.Print [20+300]                            'ok
    Debug.Print ["20"+"300"]                        'ok
    Debug.Print ["20"+300]                          'ok
    Debug.Print [inputString]                       'returns "20+300" and not 320

End Sub
```

Comment: @SMeaden - but with a different behaviour - see the updated question.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. If that last formulation doesn't work it doesn't work. Given that you have alternatives what are you hoping to find out?

Comment: @SJR - trying to find out why it does not work and how to make it work.

Comment: Don't think you can, they're not quite the same from what I get at the bottom of this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa223886(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: Read further down, it describes the difference (advantage) of each way *The advantage of using square brackets is that the code is shorter. The advantage of using Evaluate is that the argument is a string, so you can either construct the string in your code or use a Visual Basic variable.* which sort of implies that a string straight in to `[]` is not the same./

Comment: When using the [] shortcut to Evaluate you cannot build the expression from a string, as your tests demonstrate.   You enter the expression exactly as you would in a cell (minus the =).  To build an expression as a string you must use Application or Worksheett.Evaluate

Comment: Square brackets and Evaluate are not identical as using a string variable `[s]` works but `Evaluate(s)` doesn't.

Comment: @SJR - I think I am missing your point - `[s]` is exactly what does not work and `Evaluate(s)` works for me, when testing. - https://gist.github.com/Vitosh/73a5fd7099e47f4fbd22162de9070c83

Comment: Funny, behaviour in the immediate window seems different to a module. If you declare a variable as string s="Fred", both [s] and Evaluate(s) return error in the immediate window. In a module, the latter errors.

Comment: Interestingly `inputString = "20" * "300"` returns the correct result with [] for evaluation. Anyone know if the `+` operator is overloaded for addition and string concatenation in Evaluate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the link in the comment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa223886(v=office.11).aspx): "Using square brackets (for example, "[A1:C5]") is identical to calling the Evaluate method with a string argument."

I read that to mean:

`Evaluate("20+10")` is equivalent to `[20+10]` where the Evaluate function takes the string and converts to a literal interpretation before evaluating.

but `["20+10"]` is just equivalent to evaluating a string `"20+10"`

The reason `Debug.Print ["20"+"300"]` works is because VBA is great at auto-converting "20" to 20.

Comment: I have deleted my answer to get behind this answer.  It very definitely is a string argument.  I have demonstrated this is this blog post http://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2018/05/vba-com-dispid-5-gives-vba-square.html

Comment: @SMeaden - I guess that we are not going to get the source of the two `Evaluate` procedures, thus this looks like an acceptable answer.

Comment: @Vityata: I think I may have given you a wrong turn with the dual Evaluate, it was just an interesting thing I found in the type libraries that makes square brackets work.  Incidentally, if you want an expression engine then assigning the expression to a cell's formula works quite well.  C# programmers have no equivalent expression evaluator as Excel's cell parser.

Comment: @SMeaden - something like this (the wrong turn). I thought that the two `Evaluate` are concerning the `[]` and the `Evaluate`.

Comment: @Vityata: I actually think the square brackets contents being treated as a string can be a feature.  Some source fragment of other technologies can be inserted into VBA without having to double-up double quotes, http://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2018/05/vba-use-square-brackets-trick-to.html