# VBA square brackets and Range

Tags: vba, range, brackets

I just learned that square brackets be the shortcuts. For example, range("a1") is same as [a1]. May I just make sure that inside [] can only be A1 reference and can't include another variable? By the way, what's the best way to learn how "", ; and , works in Range from something like Range("a1,c3"), Range("a1","c3") and Range("A1:C3") besides forced memory?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50132024/how-to-use-square-brackets-for-a-string-evaluation-in-vba   And remembering `,` vs `:` in range notation isn't really that difficult?

Comment: If you can't remember it only takes a moment with the immediate window to verify what address is being referenced.